# Can you use an action point while Dazed to take another standard action?

Tags: dnd-4e, actions, free-action

Dazed allows you the use of ONE of your normal actions (standard, move, minor) and the use of free actions.

Using an Action Point grants the use of another Standard, move, or minor actions.

Can you use a Free action to use an action point and gain it's benefits as per usual while Dazed?

Answer (score 7):

Rules Compendium entry on Dazed:

> The creature doesn't get its normal complement of actions on its turn:
>   it can take either a standard, a move, or a minor action. The creature
>   can still take free actions.

Important thing is that it says '**get** its normal complement' rather than 'cannot spend more than one (non-free) action'.

Spending APs are a free action, so yes you can spend an Action Point to gain an extra action while dazed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. There are no restrictions in the Dazed condition that prevent spending of Action Points, nor anything that prevent gaining extra actions on your turn.

So a PC can do this, making heroic effort to struggle through when e.g. struck on the head. In addition, tactically dazing an Elite or Solo monster is also good way to force it to use its action points defensively.